# Navigating from ViewController to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to iOS development. I have an already developed application. I made my changes but I couldn't navigate from ViewController to another ViewController using push/replace/present and with or without hero package programmatically. None of them works!

I have two storyboards, each one has multiple ViewControllers.

This is what I do in AppDelegate:

```
self.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Auth", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

This is how I navigate:

```
guard let registerViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Auth", bundle: .main)
                                   .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RegisterViewController")
                                   as? RegisterViewController else { return }
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(registerViewController, animated: true)
```

I don't want to link these ViewControllers using Storyboard links because sometimes I need to make async action or navigate based on a condition before moving to another ViewController

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Make sure that your `navigationController` isn't `nil`. You should assign it somewhere

Comment: Thanks @vpoltave, You are right!

Answer (score 2):

```
**To navigate from one controller to another, you have to make navigation controller as a rootViewController as shown below:-** 

    let authVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Auth", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: authVC)
    self.window?.rootViewController = nav
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Thanks @Nexus, that would work too if you don't have NavigationController in your storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `NavigationController` in `Auth` storyboard, Or using the `UINavgiationController` programmatically as @Nexus's answer.

Comment: You should delete this answer and set the Nexus answer as accepted!